# effect of multiple convolutional layers in CNN

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

It might be very basic but just got confuse in understanding why in VGG net we have multiple convolutional layers of 3x3 filter. What specific will happen when we are taking convolution of same image twice or  more?

Comment: You might be interested in https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you read the paper that defines this network? They exactly mention this detail in the paper. https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1556

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, if you don't have a non-linear transformation in between. Then you can always collapse it into a single Convulational layer which computes the same thing.

But VGG uses ReLU activation functions. This makes it possible to learn non-linear transformations of the data.

Comment: Lets say if we have non linear ReLU in between two or more convolutional layers ( conv relu conv relu conv relu max pool) what different information i will get as compared to using single convolutional layer ( conv relu max pool).